# Bootstrap Horizontal Form - class="form-group" not working

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

Form horizontal isn't aligning the label and fields horizontally.

I have a page with a form (which has 4 fields)and a submit and a list at the bottom. I used `<p-panel >` for the form and another `<p-panel >` for the list.

I want the form to align as in bootstrap horizontal form. My bootstrap.min.css is this version -> Bootstrap v4.5.0.
My code is as below:

```
<p-messages [(value)]="msgs"></p-messages>
  <p-panel >
    <p-header>
        Header Example
    </p-header>
    <form [formGroup]="testForm"  (ngSubmit)="submitForm(testForm.value)" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group"  *ngIf="!this.isTest" style="padding:10px;">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          {{this.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"  *ngIf="this.isTest" style="padding:10px;">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Display For:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <p-listbox formControlName="names" [options]="names" [(ngModel)]="selectedName" [style]="{'width':'300px'}"  [listStyle]="{'max-height':'100px'}" [multiple]="true" [checkbox]="true" [filter]="true" optionLabel="name">
            <p-header>
              Choose
            </p-header>
          </p-listbox>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" *ngIf="this.isTest">
        <p>Selected Names: <span *ngFor="let c of selectedName" style="margin-right: 10px">{{c.name}}</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Start Date:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <p-calendar formControlName="startDate" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
          <span style="margin-left:35px">{{startDate|date}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">End Date:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <p-calendar formControlName="endDate" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
           <span style="margin-left:35px">{{endDate|date}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Message:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea rows="5" formControlName="message" class="form-control"  pInputTextArea ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >    Submit  </button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </p-panel>
  <p-panel >
    <sampleList [sampleLi]="sampleLi"></sampleList>
  </p-panel>
```

I am looking for bootstrap horizontal algnment like in this page [Text](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp)

But the above one rendered in chrome is one below the other like

```
Name: 
ABCTEST
```

In IE I am getting the sameone below the other label on top input button/date/text area below in vertical positioning. I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

My bootstrap is referenced in my angular.json file "src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css". Inspect element in chrome is pointing to the bootstrap.min.css file.

Any inputs highly appreciated.

Comment: try changing the class="form-horizontal" to class="form-inline" in form tag

Comment: @aje form-inline aligns all fields in the same line. My requirement is to align each div in a different row.

Comment: There is a new classes in bootstrap 4. here is a reference https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#horizontal-form

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it might not have worked for you because you didn't have the bootstrap embed with it.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Bootstrap Horizontal Form</title>
  </head>
  <body style="padding: 50px;">

    <form>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Choose</legend>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="option1" value="option1">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                Option 1
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="option2" value="option2">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                Option 2
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check disabled">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="option3" value="option3">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                Option 3
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><br>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">Select Names</div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="name1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="name1">
              Name 1
            </label><br>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="name2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="name2">
              Name 2
            </label><br>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="name3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="name3">
              Name 3
            </label><br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom05">Start Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="start-date" name="start-date">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom05">End Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="end-date" name="end-date">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <button style="width: 122.5%;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```